# Workaround for: PHP syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in load.php on line 1104 (when installing)

Tags: php, installation

I’ve received the error:

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /web/www/html/xxx/wordpress/wp-includes/load.php on line 1104

trying to install wordpress on a linux server.

Googling the problem I’ve found that the error depends on a older version of PHP and it is solved in PHP version 5.6 (at least). See for instance [this support issue](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/install-php-failing-at-wp-load/).

My question is: there is a workaround to solve this problem without updating PHP? (I do not control the server) Current version of PHP is 4.4.8.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress doesn't run on PHP 4. This version is **10 years** old and completely broken by any current standards. You have to use a newer PHP version, there is no workaround.

You can always look up the current [requirements on wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/).

Right now, PHP 7.3 is recommended, but 5.6 might still work.

If you can't change the PHP version, find a better host.

Comment: 5.6 is at EOL as well, whilst WP may work on it, it is no longer supported by PHP.